# Visio: Creating Automatic Numbered Label

Tags: visio

I'm currently working on creating a new stencil for several components I use in Visio and I'm stuck at the point of providing proper labels. If you use a resistor from Visio stencil it automatically generates a label "R1" (for first resistor) and "Rk" for the kth resistor. How can I do something similar for my own stencil ?

1- I need to generate a label "ABCD #" (# number automatically generated based on instance count)

2- How can I position the location of this field?

**PS:**

1- Visio components have a custom defined field which allows for this (which I don't know how to create)

2- For capacitor for example the shapesheet shows an interesting entry

*=SETF(GetRef(User.Label),"""C""&"&ThePage!User.AccumulatorCount)&SETF(GetRef(ThePage!User.AccumulatorCount),ThePage!User.AccumulatorCount+1)*

which supposedly is how the count and name are generated (I'm not sure how the AccumulatorCount is defined it differs from element to element).

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

The EventDrop ShapeSheet cells for various electrical shapes have formulas similar to the one you have discovered:
 SETF(GetRef(User.Label),"""C""&"&ThePage!User.AccumulatorCount)&SETF(GetRef(ThePage!User.AccumulatorCount),ThePage!**User.AccumulatorCount**+1)

The ShapeSheet for the page has a cell: User.AccumulatorCount for capacitors. Other User cells will be added as other shapes are dropped. You can set up your own system by adding a User cell to the page, say: User.Widget. Then you place the "Widget" version of the "SETF" formula into your own shapes.

You can create user cells by:

1. Open the ShapeSheet for the Page (right-click blank area of page, Show ShapeSheet)
2. Right-click in ShapeSheet and choose Add Section
3. Add a User-defined cells section
4. Find the User-defined cells section and similarly add rows to it via
   right-clicking
5. You change the row names by typing over the red, row-name text on the left.
6. You enter values and formulas in the cells as you would in Excel.
7. You can toggle viewing formulas vs. viewing values by pressing F5
   while in the ShapeSheet.

You have to make the User cell in the page first, so that your shape can reference it. Once your shape references the page cell, you can drag your shape into a stencil, and it will "drag the page User cell along too". So now, you can drop your Widget shape into a new document, and it will create the page User cell on the fly.

The system is basic and fragile. The count only goes up, and never down. If you have shapes with 1, 2, 3, 4 and you delete 1 and 2, the next shape will still be 5.

Comment: When was this feature added to Visio? It's in V2016 but not in V2010. And why do batteries count as capacitors?